# Intellij : does it have a Synchronization type view like eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, intellij-idea

Does anyone know if IntelliJ has a view like the Synchronization view in eclipse for working with Mercurial?

I'd like to know what incoming changes I'm about to take ?

In eclipse I can use the Synchronization view to see what is incoming and outgoing, but in Intellij I can only take the changes, not view them before hand.

Is this correct? Intellij doesn't have a view to help me when working with Mercurial?

Jeff Porter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, [it's not supported yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73130) for Mercurial. Feel free to vote.

Comment: thanks! Glad to know that I'm not blind! I've voted for it now!